# "Out of memory exception" error for which part of the code in C#? Any other alternate way?

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to let everyone know that I am totally new to C# and Object oriented programming.

Also, can anyone please show me another way to solve the question?

The question which I tried to execute is this :

```
Class Formatter

Formatter()
```

Formatting of strings is done in the constructor.

```
CapitalizeLetter(this string)
```

This method capitalizes the letters entered by the user according to the conditions given. The first letter of the passed string should be capitalized. If the string contains any space or full stop, the next letter should also be capitalized. All the other letters should be in lower cases.

**For example: ajaY malik. k**

**Output : Ajay Malik. K**

```
UrlEncode(this string)
```

It encodes the url of the portfolio entered by the user according to the given condition. If there is any space, it should be encoded as %20.

**For example: http://www.google.com/this is my sample**

**Output : http://www.google.com/this%20is%20my%20sample**

The code I tried doing in Formatter class as specified:

```
public static class Formatter
{
    static Formatter()
    {

    }

    public static string CapitalizeLetter(this string value)
    {
        string output = null;
        string[] splittedProduct = value.Split(' ','.');
        foreach (String temp in splittedProduct)
        {
            output = output + " " + temp[0].ToString().ToUpper() + temp.Substring(1).ToLower();
        }
        output = output.Trim();
        return output;
    }

    public static string UrlEncode(this string input)
    {
        string output = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (!(Convert.ToString(input[i]) == " " && Convert.ToString(input[i + 1]) == " "))
            {
                output += input[i];
            }
            output += input[input.Length - 1]; // Append last character
            output += output.Replace(" ", "%20");
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

I am receiving the error : out of memory exception.

Could someone kindly help me please ?

Comment: [Ahem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urlencode?view=netframework-4.7.2). [Ahem again](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: I can't see anything in this code that would obviously trigger the exception. How have you *determined* that these chunks of code are the source? We really need a [mcve] (`output += output.Replace(" ", "%20");` definitely looks *wrong* but I don't think can cause the exception)

Comment: @arijeet, if you want us to help solving an issue, please be sure to add the stacktrace and show us the exact line where the code fails.

Comment: These two Links dont work. Apparrently http://www.google.com/this is not a valid address, who would've thought :)

Comment: Can anyone please show me another way to solve the question?

Comment: Ah alright, my mistake, still too early

Comment: @BotMaster3000 "Brain warning BS0666: Timeout waiting for coffee maker, not enough coffee in system, aborting thought process." Been there, done th.... what was I saying? I need more coffee.

Comment: @ArijeetAcharyya I suspect your last 2 `output += ...` lines to belong **outside** the `for` loop, and the last one shouldn't have `+=`, but `=` (also you are the one who can say *for which part of the code* you get this exception)

Comment: okay I have removed the exception. But not getting desired output as specified in the CapitalizeLetter method. Someone could help me with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static string UrlEncode(this string input)
{
    string output = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (!(Convert.ToString(input[i]) == " " && Convert.ToString(input[i + 1]) == " "))
        {
            output += input[i];
        }
        output += input[input.Length - 1]; // Append last character
        output += output.Replace(" ", "%20");
    }
    return output;
}
```

For every character of `input`, you are

- Appending this character if it is not a space and its follower isn't also
- Appending the last character of `input` **with no condition**
- **Doubling** `output` replacing spaces in the second part **with no condition**

Just have a look at the output of `Console.WriteLine("Blabla".UrlEncode());`:

```
BaBalaBaBalaaaBaBalaBaBalaaabaBaBalaBaBalaaaBaBalaBaBalaaabalaBaBalaBaBalaaaBaBalaBaBalaaabaBaBalaBaBalaaaBaBalaBaBalaaabala
```

No wonder why you get `OutOfMemoryException` if you try this with quite a long `input`

To get rid of this Exception, you should **at least** move your two `output +=` lines **outside** the loop, and replace the last `+=` with `=`:

```
public static string UrlEncode(this string input)
{
    string output = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (!(Convert.ToString(input[i]) == " " && Convert.ToString(input[i + 1]) == " "))
        {
            output += input[i];
        }
    }
    output += input[input.Length - 1]; // Append last character
    output = output.Replace(" ", "%20");
    return output;
}
```

Also, as already noted, maybe having just

```
public static string UrlEncode(this string input)
{
    return input.Replace(" ", "%20");
}
```

could be enough for your problem.